# C# InvalidOperationException when creating a new SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server

I`ve written some code to establish a connection to SQL Server, then execute select procedure to take all data from my data table in SQL server, but it throw a InvalidOperationException at the command of declare a new SqlDataAdapter, please help me to fix this error.

```
public class dBConnect
{
    //create SQLconnection variable
    private SqlConnection con;
    //create default constructor that passing a string to con
    public dBConnect()
    {
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=Trump\SQLEXPRESS;
        Database=Demo;User Id=sa;Password = stevejobs;");
        }
        catch(Exception exCon)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to database: {0}", exCon);
        }
    }
    //create Select method to Pour the data into the DataTable
    public DataTable SelectAll(string procName, SqlParameter[] para = null)
    {
        //create a DataTable to store Data from DB
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //create SQLCommand
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procName, con);
        //declare that cmdType is sp
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //input parameter of cmd
        if (para != null)
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(para);
        //create dataAdapter object

        //InvalidOperationException was thrown at here
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        //declare that cmd is select command of da 
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        //use try/catch/finally to establish a connection
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch(Exception sqlEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"：Unable to establish a connection: {0}", sqlEx);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I believe it means there is an issue with the SQL command itself, so you should check those first. Additionally, you should probably wrap your SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and SqlDataAdapter in using statements.

Comment: It's a little bit weird here. At the first time I connect to database through a login form, everything is OK. But when I close the main form and get back to Login form, and try to login again, error dialog appear. The content of this dialog is "connectionstring property has not been initialized".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up your code a bit here:

```
public DataTable SelectAll(string procName, SqlParameter[] para = null)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procName, con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        if (para != null)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(para);

                        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {

                            da.Fill(dt);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception sqlEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"：Unable to establish a connection: {0}", sqlEx);
            }

            return dt;

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should:

```
cmd.CommandText = "your Stored Procedure here.";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//input parameter of cmd
if (para != null)
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(para);
//create dataAdapter object
```

Put your `con.Open();` above

or

Just take a look at this steps

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
     con.Open();
      using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
      {
       //sample stored procedure with parameter:
       // "exec yourstoredProcedureName '" + param1+ "','" + param2+ "'";
       cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure Here";
       cmd.CommandType =CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            adp.Fill(dt);
             return dt;
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Be carefull on your "para" becuse it is an array.. just a "Heads Up".